# Instructing Vivado HLS directive editor for utilizing custom IPs to implement various functions

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, vivado-hls

The directive editor of Vivado HLS provides different options for "Resource" directive. Is it possible to instruct HLS to use my custom designed IPs for some operations? For example: for implementing multipliers, HLS provides DSP based multipliers. But can I instruct HLS to use my own custom designed multiplier IP for implementing multipliers during synthesis operation?

*I think Vivado HLS also supports multiplier implementation without using DSP blocks. But I am looking for using my own custom multiplier IP.*

Comment: Can this be done using "#pragma HLS allocation core='your IP'"?

Comment: I think this might work if I could somehow add my custom IP to the HLS IP catalog. In Vivado, I can add my custom IPs to the IP catalog. But in Vivado HLS, I cannot find a method to include my custom IP (designed with Vivado) in the IP catalog of Vivado HLS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, as of Vivado HLS 2018.2 you cannot integrate custom Verilog IP into a top level HLS design.

A possible workaround would be to add the necessary input/output ports to the top level HLS function and then connect them to the desired IP instance. Of course, doing that for every multiplier might be too cumbersome.